# win32k.pdb mismatched or not found

Tags: windbg, visual-studio-debugging, pdb-files

I'm using PDB files provided by msdl.
Symchk and windbg were working fine till last week. But after an update (I think) suddenly I'm getting this message in symchk and every program which uses it.

Command: `symchk.exe /v /r c:\windows\system32\win32k.sys /s SRV*c:\symbols\*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`

This is the verbose output of symchk:

```
[SYMCHK] Using search path "SRV*c:\symbols\*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols"
SYMCHK: win32k.sys           FAILED  - win32k.pdb mismatched or not found

SYMCHK: FAILED files = 1
SYMCHK: PASSED + IGNORED files = 0
[SYMCHK] Searching for symbols to c:\windows\system32\win32k.sys in path SRV*c:\symbols\*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: SRV*c:\symbols\*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
DBGHELP: No header for c:\windows\system32\win32k.sys.  Searching for image on disk
DBGHELP: c:\windows\system32\win32k.sys - OK
SYMSRV:  c:\symbols\win32k.pdb\B271277F931B479F930225DE8E4DD5392\win32k.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/win32k.pdb/B271277F931B479F930225DE8E4DD5392/win32k.pdb not found
DBGHELP: win32k - no symbols loaded
[SYMCHK] MODULE64 Info ----------------------
[SYMCHK] Struct size: 1680 bytes
[SYMCHK] Base: 0xFFFFF97FFF000000
[SYMCHK] Image size: 3305472 bytes
[SYMCHK] Date: 0x59e533c6
[SYMCHK] Checksum: 0x00320cf6
[SYMCHK] NumSyms: 0
[SYMCHK] SymType: SymNone
[SYMCHK] ModName: win32k
[SYMCHK] ImageName: c:\windows\system32\win32k.sys
[SYMCHK] LoadedImage: c:\windows\system32\win32k.sys
[SYMCHK] PDB: ""
[SYMCHK] CV: RSDS
[SYMCHK] CV DWORD: 0x53445352
[SYMCHK] CV Data:  win32k.pdb
[SYMCHK] PDB Sig:  0
[SYMCHK] PDB7 Sig: {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
[SYMCHK] Age: 0
[SYMCHK] PDB Matched:  TRUE
[SYMCHK] DBG Matched:  TRUE
[SYMCHK] Line nubmers: FALSE
[SYMCHK] Global syms:  FALSE
[SYMCHK] Type Info:    FALSE
[SYMCHK] ------------------------------------
SymbolCheckVersion  0x00000002
Result              0x00010001
DbgFilename         win32k.dbg
DbgTimeDateStamp    0x00000000
DbgSizeOfImage      0x00000000
DbgChecksum         0x00000000
PdbFilename         win32k.pdb
PdbSignature        {B271277F-931B-479F-9302-25DE8E4DD539}
PdbDbiAge           0x00000002
[SYMCHK] [ 0x00000000 - 0x00010001 ] Checked "c:\windows\system32\win32k.sys"
```

I tried deleting the symbols folder on my PC. no effect. I can get symbols for other files like ntoskrnl.exe. This command works like a charm on the latest windows 10; but occurs in windows 7. No other program like VS2017 and windbg can get the PDB files either.

Comment: Symbols (and especially for win32k it seems) are not pushed directly after an update by MS to their symbol server. Sometimes the symbols are even not pushed at all or disappear. It happens quite frequently lately... So your best option is to wait.

Comment: try mailing windbgfb@microsoft.com with a report someone like andy luhrs normally replies back

Comment: I've emailed them. I'll post their reply